# Python 3.x get JSON from URL

Tags: python, json, url, python-3.x, get

Hello fellow Programmers,

today I wanted to get some JSON Data from this website using Python 3.3: http://ladv.de/api/-apikey-redacted-/ausDetail?id=884&wettbewerbe=true&all=true

The official API tells me that calling this URL returns some JSON Data. But if I use the following code to get it (which I found on stackoverflow, too), it throws an error:

```
import urllib.request
import json

request = 'http://ladv.de/api/mmetzger/ausDetail?id=884&wettbewerbe=true&all=true'
response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
obj = json.load(response)
str_response = response.readall().decode('utf-8')
obj = json.loads(str_response)
print(obj)
```

prints out

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/ladvclient/testscrape.py", line 5, in <module>
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\urllib\request.py", line 156, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\urllib\request.py", line 475, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\urllib\request.py", line 587, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\urllib\request.py", line 513, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\urllib\request.py", line 447, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\urllib\request.py", line 595, in http_error_default
        raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
    urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
```

Where is the bug, and what is the correct code?
Thanks in advance,

forumfresser

Comment: Please don't remove the question's content :).

Comment: I think that 404: Not Found tells everything, but if not just try to open the link in some browser.

Comment: The title is not covering problem as you fetch a specific site and get a not found which has nothing to do with fetching data using python. Using curl would yield the same not found result.

Answer (score 8):

The site you're trying to fetch is not available, as seen here:

http://ladv.de/api/-apikey-redacted-/ausDetail?id=884&wettbewerbe=true&all=true

You could also just read the error message by yourself:

```
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
```